# Jump to last formula row that displays data

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I've created a template on a worksheet that just pulls data from a data source worksheet.  So there are formulas on rows 9-10,000 and I've turned the option to display 0 off so that I only see how much data there is on the source worksheet.

I'm trying to create a macro that jumps to the bottom row of displayed data (say, row 2,500), but since there are formulas in the rows below that just aren't displaying a result, it jumps to row 10,000 instead.

How can I make it ignore all those blank formula rows and just stop at the last one with displayed data?

Comment: To directly answer your question, you'll have to put a loop that tests each row and stops when it hit your zero row. However, I would consider an alternative approach of just pulling relevant rows to your template worksheet (possibly using the `filter()` function), then your macro would work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FindLastRowWithData

dim i as integer
dim bFound as boolean
dim iColumn as integer
dim ws as worksheet
dim iFoundRow as integer

set ws as ActiveSheet
bFound = false

'set which column to test
iColumn = 1

for i = [lastrow]* to 2
    if not bFound then
        if not ws.cells(i,iColumn).value = "" then
            bFound = true
            iFoundRow = i
        end if
    end if
next i

msgbox "your last row where the formula shows a result is " & i

end sub
```

Note I did not test run this code as I wrote it in notepad, but it should get you most of the way to finding the last row containing a displayed result of your formula.

'* I leave it to you to determine what your actual last row is. If you know it, you can hardcode here; if it might vary, there are 100 Q&A's in this stack or on SO about how to find the last used row in Excel VBA.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I've tried this but I'm getting an Invalid Inside Procedure error and it highlights "option explicit."  Apologies if this is super basic - I'm learning as I go here.

Comment: @MarkTraylor Option Explicit is a setting that you have to set on the first line of code, basically. the error is telling you you have that command inside a sub or function. Option Explicit means you have to declare (`Dim`) all variables before using them, which is a good habit to get into... but you can do more research on that if you like. this code should run in a sub on its own if you omit it.

Comment: ...which if you do, you'll need to move all the `Dim` lines to below the `Sub FindLastRowWithData` line as well. I'm pretty sure working with `Option Explicit` off means you _can_ `Dim` variables, you just don't _have_ to.

Comment: @MarkTraylor I edited the answer to rearrange those first few lines and also to add a note I had forgotten about the fact that you will need to define your overall last row before running this code

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code jumping to the last non-zero cell in first column:

```
Sub JumpToLastValue()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    LastRow = Application.Evaluate("=MAX(FILTER(ROW(A:A),A:A>0))")
    ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow, 1).Activate
End Sub
```

(it works only in Excel365)

[image]

Comment: This appears to have worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Faster than testing each row would be to use GoTo, which presumably VBA can.

This assumes you have at least one column (sounds like more than one, but at least one) that has nothing but data down to some point, say row 2500, as in your post for example, and then formulas are all that exist below that point.

Select the column's start which is presumably known to contain data ("constants" in Excel's way of labelling it). Then use GoTo to find a formula. As described above, this will necessarily be the first formula following the data, so long as you selected the first cell of that column in the data/formula region. Then, also necessarily, the cell just above is the last data cell.

Specific example:  Say column A had formulas from cells A9 through A10000. Data replaced those formulas, row by row, for some time and now the first cell in the column with a formula is cell A2501. All above it have data ("constants"). Note that this might differ in other columns as some formulas might be useful in them. But your macro selects ONLY column A, then the first candidate cell in it (A9), and uses GoTo to find the first formula in it. That is cell A2501. It then reports the cell above that (A2500) as being the last cell with data, hence the last row with data. It can finally jump to that row for you.

The two likely seeming other approaches would be testing row (hopefully "cell", not whole row, but... as needed) after row until a formula is found and reporting the cell just above's row.

An alternative that would be faster after the region becomes >50% data would be to do that search from the bottom up instead.

One might also have it search cells for a specific string that should be in the formulas that can be found. That'd likely have to be dynamic.

Of course, one could search cell properties until one found a formula, then pick the row above.

None of these would be nearly as fast. Modern computers? Who knows, you might not even notice the difference, but a single thing to look for, using built-in capability for searching, seems likely far faster. (By "built-in" I mean Excel and VBA's out-of-the-box programming routines, not search routines you have to develop. Presumably theirs are faster from being very carefully crafted and implemented while yours is ad hoc and maybe not as optimized for the task. Not to mention them having access to (imagined, but still... maybe) internal indexes that could greatly speed such a search.)

Comment: "Say column A had formulas from cells A9 through A10000. Data replaced those formulas, row by row, for some time and now the first cell in the column with a formula is cell A2501. All above it have data ("constants")." This doesn't sound like what OP is describing, at all